# Magento Server Side Optimization

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento2.2, performance

Many times we heared that server side optimization is the first thing we should consider for better performance. What's included in server side optimization?

I try to find and found increase RAM and install varnish are only 2 things we can do for server side optimization.

Is there any other things we can do on server side to optimize the magento's performance?

What else we can do to optimize Magento on  server side?

Is there any different method for Magento 2 on server side?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read this please https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_perf-optimize.html

Comment: A few suggestions here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/272527/70343