# Is it possible to make Magento 2 fast (i.e. < 2s page load) without using any caching?

Tags: magento2, cache, performance

In web development it's good practice to ensure that your applications perform sufficiently well [without relying on a cache](https://medium.com/@mauridb/caching-is-not-what-you-think-it-is-5104f8891b51). Caching should not be used as a crutch or a permanent solution to mask otherwise poor performance.

So my question is: is it possible to achieve acceptably performant (i.e. under two second) page loads in Magento 2 without using any caching, and if so, how?

Comment: You have raised a good point. +1

Comment: Don't use a custom or "premium" theme with 900 queries per category view.

Comment: Hell no, even with caching it is a challenge to make it loads in under 2 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is: no you can not build any decent application and **keep** page load in multiuser environment faster than 2 seconds. 
you would say you can, yes, but only for a limited time.

you have to understand, that even if you have perfect code, light theme, simple products - your system load will grow proportionally to:

```
1 - frontend requests
2 - database writes
```

> cache is not build for speed, but to lower your servers load and cut
>   on infrastructure costs. avoiding cache is the last thing you would do
>   if your are for profit.

performance is not only one request. all these fancy pagespeed metrics only for fun.

hiding errors and poor code with cache is another problem.

this is why you have to run staging setups. test all your changes and updates with `PROFILER`.

also many magento users trying to enable all the possible caches, but usually this makes site speed even worse. it depends.

Comment: At leat one says "no" :)

Comment: I agree completely with this no answer. No way you can get magento to load in under 2 seconds. I've spent most of the last 6 years of working in m1 and m2 'masking' such problems with various cache mechanisms (full page, compiled code in memory and reverse proxy),  cdns, session management, HHVM, various versions of php..., the list goes on

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have done this one before.

1. Inspect every installed 3rd-party extension, and disable useless extensions on your website
2. Choose the fastest hosting you can afford
3. Turn Production Mode On
4. Never Use JS Bundling
   [image]
5. Enable CSS/JS Minification
   [image]
6. Last and most importantly, enable profiler and check all the files (.phtml) and events, check which are taking more time to execute. And remember even 0.5 sec for a file or event is also huge time for a single file/event.

Answer (score 0):

Some secret of Speeding up Magento is hidden in its `.htaccess` file itself.  You need to carefully edit the below things in `.htaccess` file:

- **Enable Output Compression**
- **Enable Expires Headers**

Also, you can consider the below points:

1. Change default setting from Magento Admin:

   - **Merge CSS and Javascript files**
   - **Enable Flat Catalog**
2. Clean Magento database

Source: https://www.appseconnect.com/speed-up-your-magento-store-from-slow-to-insanely-fast/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible ensuring best practices can help loading your site less than 2 seconds.

> 1. Make use of **Profiler** to check the time taken for files to load, especially for third party modules and your custom modules. Check and
>      ensure to load them in lesser time.
>
>    php bin/magento dev:profiler:enable html
>
>    php bin/magento dev:profiler:enable csvfile
> 2. **Minify** your HTML, CSS and js files.
> 3. **Merge** your CSS and JS files.
> 4. Make sure you serve **optimized images** and your images are not heavy.
> 5. Switch your website to **production mode** while serving end users.
> 6. Make sure you **compress** your files.
> 7. Optimize your server to reduce the server response time.
> 8. Check if bundling works to reduce the loading time, if it increases the page size heavy disable it.
> 9. Also try using **Google Page Speed Module** in your Server so you can configure it in the best way to load your site in short span of
>      time. You can also optimize and convert images to best fit for your
>      site.